# How do I remove duplicates row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

My table name is `emails`.

My table structures looks like:

[image]

I want to remove all of the duplicated emails. I tried this query:

```
DELETE FROM emails WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT MIN(email)
    FROM emails GROUP BY email)
```

But with no result. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you are looking for would use `id`, not `email`:

```
DELETE FROM emails
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM emails GROUP BY email) ;
```

EDIT:

You are using MySQL.  You can get around this with the subquery hack:

```
DELETE FROM emails
    WHERE id NOT IN (select minid from (SELECT MIN(id) as minid FROM emails GROUP BY email) e) ;
```

Or, you can use a `join`:

```
delete e
    from emails e left outer join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from emails
          group by email
         ) em
         on e.id = e.minid
    where em.id is null;
```

Comment: it gives me this : You can't specify target table 'emails' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

--CREATE a Temporary table

```
create table IDsToRemove (ID Int)
INSERT INTO IDStoRemove
     SELECT MIN(id) _
            FROM emails GROUP BY email 


      DELETE FROM emails WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id from IDStoRemove)
```

I don't know the exact mySQL syntax, but should give you the idea

Comment: it gives me this : You can't specify target table 'emails' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Not you can't use the COUNT(*) > 1, my error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you (or someone) wants to delete records that are unique, I'll just leave this stolen answer here[0].

```
DELETE Emails 
FROM Emails
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) as id, email, pwd
    FROM Emails
    GROUP BY email, pwd
  ) as KeepRows ON
  Emails.id = KeepRows.id
WHERE
  KeepRows.id IS NULL
```

0.[How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)